# Why is there no "parabolic abberation" in lenses?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

I am trying to understand what an "ideal" lens would look like. Spherical surfaces are not correct, as these produce [spherical aberration](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Optics/BSc_Optics_(Konijnenberg_Adam_and_Urbach)/06%3A_Scalar_diffraction_optics/6.09%3A_Fourier_Optics).

This article [here](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Optics/BSc_Optics_(Konijnenberg_Adam_and_Urbach)/06%3A_Scalar_diffraction_optics/6.09%3A_Fourier_Optics), is really useful. It 'derives' the thin lens equation by using the following reasoning.

1. Start with a point source at distance $f$ from some plane, explicitly at the point $(0,0,-f)$.
2. Record the phase that arrives at the plane $z=0$ as a function of $(x,y)$.
3. Delay the phase at point $(x,y)$ until every point in the plane has the same phase. The wave from the point source is now collimated to a beam. A lens that adds this delay to an incoming light beam is now an ideal thin lens

According to geometric optics, the wave that arrives at the plane in point $(x,y)$ is given by

$$\frac{e^{-ik\sqrt{x^2+y^2+f^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+f^2}}$$

So, the phase that arrives at point $(x,y,0)$ is $\phi(x,y)=-k\sqrt{x^2+y^2+f^2}$. To get a plane wave, our lens must just add the negative of this phase as our transfer function: $\Delta \phi=k\sqrt{x^2+y^2+f^2}$.

If we assume that $r^2=x^2+y^2$ is much smaller than $f$, we can approximate the square root function as a quadratic equation (is this the paraxial equation?).

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+f^2}\approx f+\frac{x^2+y^2}{2f}.$$

This predict a parabolic lens as an ideal thin lens. You can approximate this using a spherical lens, since
$$2f-\sqrt{f^2-x^2-y^2}\approx f+\frac{x^2+y^2}{2f}$$

Now my question is, why are parabolic lenses often considered ideal? The ideal lens, according to my derivation, should be of the form $
\sqrt{r^2+f^2}$. The parabolic lens is then just an approximation. If we plot the 4-th order of the Taylor series, we see the approximation is as far off as a spherical lens is off from a parabolic lens.
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
 \text{Expression} & \text{Series Approx.} \\\\
\hline
 \sqrt{f^2+x^2} &f+\frac{x^2}{2 f}  -\frac{x^4}{8 f^3}\\\\
 \frac{x^2}{2 f}+f & f+\frac{x^2}{2 f} \\\\
 2 f-\sqrt{f^2-x^2} & f+\frac{x^2}{2 f}  +\frac{x^4}{8 f^3} \\\\
\end{array}
$$

If we plot it, the difference between the approximations is again comparable.

[image]

So again, why aren't parabolic abberations a thing?

Comment: because it has an awful 3rd order coma distortion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is partly historical. The surfaces of a lens must typically be accurate to about a wavelength of light. This is far more precise than you can do with a lathe. Surfaces were ground to shape and polished. A sphere is the only shape that can be easily ground, so lenses have spherical surfaces.

Though a skilled craftsman can make an aspherical shape by applying pressure to the center during grinding. An now molding has gotten good enough for lenses.

Also lenses were designed by ray tracking, not wavefront propagation. So abberations are developed with them in mind. Spherical abberation is the abberation caused by the shape you could make. See [Is there a more accurate form of the mirror equation 1f=1u+1v
?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342043/37364) for more.

Also, sometimes a parabola is not the ideal surface. See [Ideal surface for a perfect lens](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/730011/37364)

Comment: So would you say that in this case a hyperbolic lens is ideal?

Comment: If all you want to do is taken an expanding spherical wave from an on axis point to a collimated bean, then a hyperbola is ideal. If you want to focus a collimated beam to an on axis point, the ideal shape is an ellipsoid. If you want to do both of these things, neither is ideal. You might design a shape that does both well enough. Or more likely, a series of lenses.